# Difference between overflow-wrap: anywhere & overflow-wrap: break-word?

Tags: css

About the new css spec `overflow-wrap`:

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap) says `break-word` is the same as `anywhere` **except**

> soft wrap opportunities introduced by the word break are NOT considered when calculating min-content intrinsic sizes.

What does it mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most of the time they're very similar.

One case when they're different: when you have a super long word (like an url) that is longer than the width of the container, and the container is a flex item with flex-grow, then `anywhere` will break the long word, whereas `break-word` will try to grow aggressively and avoid breaking the word when possible, which may squeeze other flex items out of proportion.

In this case, `anywhere` is more likely what you want. If that's true, you might as well do this:

```css
overflow-wrap: break-word;
overflow-wrap: anywhere;
```

...because Safari supports of `break-word` is earlier than `anywhere`, so in old versions of Safari that does't support `anywhere`, the 2nd line will be ignored, which is not too bad.